# Paginação com spring data

Tags: java, spring, paginação, spring-data, spring-jpa

Tenho uma lista de clientes por vendedor e estou tentando criar uma paginação para mostrar de 10 e 10 clientes no meu modal em PHP. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço, porque ainda não sou bom no spring data.

Segue abaixo o meu repositório:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import br.com.alpha.core.modelo.entidades.Cliente;

public interface ClienteRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

    List<Cliente> findByNomeStartingWithAndVendedorEquals(String nome, Integer vendedor);

}
```

Comment: Olá Bruno, consegui sim! E foi bem simples, como eu nunca tinha feito uma paginação dessas fiquei quase louco kkkkk mas deu tudo certo.  Um amigo desse Site postou esse link baixe ele pois tem um exemplo bem simplificado e você vai entender de cara. Foi isso que ele postou "Em um dos meus projetos utilizei esta solução, toda a sua documentação está no github: https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect"

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public interface ClienteRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

    Page<Cliente> findByNomeStartingWithAndVendedorEquals(String nome, Integer vendedor,  Pageable pageRequest);

}
```

no método que chama a consulta vc faz da seguinte forma:

```
public Page<Cliente> buscarCliente(String nome, Integer vendedor,  Pageable pageRequest) {


/*
* page se refere a página de paginação que a consulta retornará o valor (Int)
*linesPerPage = quantidade de objetos que irá retornar em cada página
* direction = Se vai ordenar de forma crescente ou não ASC ou DESC
*orderBy = trata-se do campo utilizado na ordenação
*
*/

PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, linesPerPage, Direction.valueOf(direction), orderBy);

Page<Cliente> clientes = clienteRepository.findByNomeStartingWithAndVendedorEquals(String nome, Integer vendedor,  pageRequest);
}
```

Lembre que na classe de serviço vc deve injetar a classe ClienteRepository;
Deve-se atribuir valores nas variáveis utilizadas na criação do objeto pageRequest no momento da construção, deixei o comentário para que vc coloque os valores de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode pesquisar o uso do PageRequest do Spring, com ele você já chama a consulta passando esse objeto como retorno(vocÊ vai passar o offset, o total) e ele te retorna uma paginação já feita.

Pode ver mais sobre o PageRequest aqui : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html